# Optimize Rails RSpec Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a test for my Rails 4 app and I'm pretty new to using RSpec. I have a controller named AppsController which has the standard index, new, show, create... methods and they all work the way Rails suggest Etc. "new" creates a new instance of the object and create actually saves it, show, shows it and index shows all of the object. Here are my current tests can anyone see any potential problems or things that i could improve?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :developer do
    email 'example@me.com'
    password 'new_york'
    password_confirmation 'new_york'
    tos '1'
  end

  factory :app do
    name 'New App'
    tos '1'
  end

  factory :invalid_app, parent: :app do
    name 'nil'
    tos '0'
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'spec_helper'

def create_valid!
  post :create, app: app_attributes
end

def create_invalid!
  post :create, app: app_invalid_attributes
end

def show!
  get :show, id: app
end

def update_valid!
  put :update, id: app, app: app_attributes
end

def update_invalid!
  put :update, id: app, app: app_invalid_attributes
end

def delete!
  delete :destroy, id: app
end

def http_success
  expect(response).to be_success
end

def expect_template(view)
  expect(response).to render_template(view)
end

describe AppsController do
  render_views

  before(:each) do
    @developer = FactoryGirl.create(:developer)
    @developer.confirm!
    sign_in @developer
  end

  let(:app) { FactoryGirl.create(:app, developer: @developer) }
  let(:app_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:app) }
  let(:app_invalid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:invalid_app) }

  describe 'GET #index' do
    it 'responds with an HTTP 200 status' do
      get :index
      http_success
    end

    it 'renders the :index view' do
      get :index
      expect_template(:index)
    end

    it 'populates @apps with the current_developers apps' do
      app = FactoryGirl.create(:app, :developer => @developer)
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:app)).to eq([app])
    end
  end

  describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'with valid parameters' do
      it 'creates a new app' do
        expect { create_valid!
        }.to change(App, :count).by(1)
      end

      it 'redirects to the new app keys' do
        create_valid!
        expect(response).to redirect_to keys_app_path(App.last)
      end
    end

    context 'with invalid parameters' do
      it 'does not create the new app' do
        expect { create_invalid!
        }.to_not change(App, :count)
      end

      it 'renders the :new view' do
        create_invalid!
        expect_template(:new)
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'GET #show' do
    it 'responds with an HTTP 200 status' do
      show!
      http_success
    end

    it 'renders the :show view' do
      show!
      expect_template(:show)
    end

    it 'populates @app with the requested app' do
      show!
      expect(assigns(:app)).to eq(app)
    end
  end

  describe 'PUT #update' do
    context 'with valid parameters' do
      it 'locates the requested app' do
        update_valid!
        expect(assigns(:app)).to eq(app)
      end

      it 'changes app attributes' do
        update_valid!
        expect(app.name).to eq('Updated App')
      end

      it 'redirects to the updated app' do
        update_valid!
        expect(response).to redirect_to app
      end
    end

    context 'with invalid parameters' do
      it 'locates the requested app' do
        update_invalid!
        expect(assigns(:app)).to eq(app)
      end

      it 'does not change app attributes' do
        update_invalid!
        expect(app.name).to_not eq('Updated App')
      end

      it 'renders the :edit view' do
        update_invalid!
        expect_template(:edit)
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'DELETE #destroy' do
    it 'deletes the app' do
      expect { delete!
      }.to change(App, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it 'redirects to apps#index' do
      delete!
      expect(response).to redirect_to apps_url
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
count should have been changed by -1, but was changed by 0 - on DELETE #destroy

expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]> - on POST #create

expected: "Updated App"
     got: "New App"     - on PUT #update

expecting <"edit"> but rendering with <[]> - on PUT #update

expected: [#<App id: nil, unique_id: "rOIc5p", developer_id: 18, name: "New App">]
     got: nil           - on GET #index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small thing - your #http_success method is testing the exact same thing twice.

You could also factor out the references to app by putting a #let statement right after your #before block:

```
let(:app) { FactoryGirl.create(:app, developer: @developer) }
```

then in your specs, just

```
it 'renders the :show view' do
  get :show, id: app
  expect_template(:show)
end
```

Edit:
Then the order of operations will be 1) the @developer is created in the #before block, 2) the spec is entered, 3) at the first reference to `app` in the spec, the #let block will create an instance of an app.

That means you can't factor out the app creation in the #index spec, because in that case the spec will call the action before it creates the app.

Comment: Thank you, do i also have to add 'developer' to the FactoryConfig under 'app' because the Developer has_many apps, or is it fine the way it is and also for the 'new' method my controller sets it up this way '@app = current_developer.apps.new', how can i add a test for that?

Comment: Thank you i fixed it and the index test works now, any suggestions for the comment above?

Comment: I don't disagree with any of that.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I thought of, reading your code:

You don't need to include parens on method calls taking no arguments. Just `http_success` will work.

You should get try to use the modern RSpec expectation syntax consistently. Instead of `assigns(:app).should eq(app)`, use `expect(assigns(:app)).to eq(app)`. (There's one exception to this, which is expectations on mocks (ie. `should_receive(:message)`), which will only take on the modern expect-to syntax as of [RSpec 3](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2013/07/the-plan-for-rspec-3).

For controller specs, I like to create little methods for each action that actually invokes the action. You'll notice you call `get :show, id: app` several times in the `GET #show` specs. To DRY up your specs a little more, you could instead write the following method within the `describe` block:

```
def show!
  get :show, id: app
end
```

Try to use one Hash syntax consistently. What's more, Rails 4 can't be run with Ruby 1.8, so there's (nearly) no reason to use the hash-rocket Hash syntax.

If I'm getting really, really picky, I usually consider instance variables in a spec to be a smell. In almost all cases, instance variables should be refactored to a memoized `let`/`given` blocks.

If I'm getting really, really, *really* picky, I prefer to think of controller specs such as yours as strictly a **unit test** of the controller, not an integration test (that's what Capybara is for), and as such you shouldn't be exercising your model layer at all. You should only be testing that your controller is sending the right messages to the model layer. In other words, all the model layer stuff should be stubbed out. For example:

```
describe 'GET #show' do
  let(:app) { stub(:app) }

  before do
    App.stub(:find).and_return(app)
  end

  it 'populates @app' do
    get :show, id: app
    assigns(:app).should eq(app)
  end
end
```

I know this last is a personal preference, not a metaphysical truth or even necessarily a wide-spread standard convention, so you may choose to take it or leave it. I prefer it, because it keeps my specs very speedy, and gives me a very clear heuristic for when my controller actions are doing too much, and I might need to consider refactoring. It could be a good habit to get into.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i refactored out some methods to def and i update the syntax. As far as the stubbed tests go i am not sure how to implement them with what i currently have. Also when i run the spec tests i get 13 passed and 5 failed. I updated my question with my full code and the exact errors at the bottom, i'm not sure whats causing this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not certain but I suspect your `invalid app` factory may be wrong.  Did you mean

```
  factory :invalid_app, parent: :app do
    name nil
    tos '0'
  end
```

- `nil` as a ruby `NilClass` not `"nil"` as a string?

As for other comments about cleanup and stuff, here are a few of my thoughts.

You can avoid the need for some of your helper methods and duplication by using `before` blocks for each `describe`.  Taking just your index tests you could have something more like

```
describe 'GET #index' do
  before do
    get :index
  end
  it 'responds with an HTTP 200 status' do
    http_success
  end

  it 'renders the :index view' do
    expect_template(:index)
  end

  it 'populates @apps with the current_developers apps' do
    expect(assigns(:app)).to eq([app])
  end
end
```

Notice also that you don't need to recreate `app` because your `let` is doing it as necessary.

On the failures, I suspect the `delete` count change could be failing because inside the expectation, the test framework is creating a new app (from the `let`) and then deleting it leading to a count change of 0.  For that test, you need to make sure you're `app` is created outside of your expectation.  Because you are using `let`, you could do that like this:

```
describe 'DELETE #destroy' do
  it 'deletes the app' do
    # ensure that app is already created
    app
    expect { 
      delete!
    }.to change(App, :count).by(-1)
  end
end
```

alternatively, change the `let` to a `let!` which will force the creation before the specs actually run.

As for other failures, thought @DanielWright suggested the helper methods, I find those complicate the debug.  I can't see where you set the app name to "Updated App", for example.  Perhaps a clearer test (for that particular one) would not use the helper methods but could be more explicit.  Something like

```
describe 'PUT #update' do
  let(:app_attributes) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:app, name: 'The New App Name') }
  before do
    put :update, id: app, app: app_attributes
  end
  context 'with valid parameters' do
    it 'locates the requested app' do
      expect(assigns(:app)).to eq(app)
    end

    it 'changes app attributes' do
      # notice the reload which will make sure you refetch this from the db
      expect(app.reload.name).to eq('The New App Name')
    end

    it 'redirects to the updated app' do
      expect(response).to redirect_to app
    end
  end
end
```

For the other errors, you might want to start debugging your code.  Are you certain it should work?  Have you looked at output logs?  Maybe the tests are doing there job and finding errors in your controller code.  Have you done any step-through debugging?